# HKWirelessHD SDK - Build Errors

Tags: audio

I keep getting errors when attempting to deploy my app or the sample apps to my emulator. It doesn't matter whether I'm working with iOS or Android.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the SDK only supports ARM, so all applications should be deployed to your iOS or Android device.